# Git repository error message with JFileChooser

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, git, jfilechooser

I'm using Eclipse. When I use a JFileChooser, the message `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` keeps appearing in the console. The same message is printed again whenever I navigate to a new folder. I also noticed that if I navigate into a folder that is a git repository, the console prints the directory path instead of the error message.

Here is the code that I used:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class JFileChooserTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFileChooser test = new JFileChooser ();
        test.showOpenDialog (null);
    }   
}
```

I tried running the above code in Doctor Java, and no error messages appeared, so I think the problem has something to do with Eclipse.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to turn off these messages?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue on my Win7 box (I found your question while Googling). In my case, my code was:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new File("C:\\test.html").toURI());
```

I got exactly the same error message (on error output, without any Exception): `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I'm using JDK 1.7.0_51.

I noticed that this issue occurs only when I start my application with Eclipse or a Batch file. Using a .exe launcher, the code works as expected, no error message.
Using "Process Monitor" tool I noticed that my java.exe process performs Windows Registry lookup (surely to get the right application to open my file) that finally leads to Git shell extension DLL, then my process starts the command "git rev-parse --show-prefix". I was using Git 1.7.11 with windows shell extension from http://msysgit.github.io. After uninstalling Git, I don't get this error message anymore, but the requested web page is still not opened :(

Definitely not a `JFileChooser` issue only. But surely relative to Windows shell extensions while JVM native stuff is playing with files...

Comment: I have the same behavior here...your answer explains it. thx. ;-)